# Javascript removeEventListener does not work

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
function handleCarInfoCopy(admin) {
    function changeClipBoard(evt) {
        evt.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", "No copy allowed");
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
    if (admin === false) {
        document.addEventListener("copy", changeClipBoard, false);
    } else {
        document.removeEventListener("copy", changeClipBoard, false);
    }
}
```

The problem is that `removeEventListener` never works. Even after the event listener has been successfully created, it won't remove it, after `admin` variable changes to `true`. Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Removing an event handler needs to be done using the _exact same_ function object, that was used to add it in the first place. `changeClipBoard` is local to your `handleCarInfoCopy` function here, so each time the latter gets called, a _new_ `changeClipBoard` is created in the outer one's scope.

Comment: I hope this link help :-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63941876/javascript-removeeventlistener-not-doing-anything-with-anonymous-function-no

Comment: Here are 2 examples on how to solve the issue for your specific scenario. https://gist.github.com/3limin4t0r/5bc8485d987c293190e985de967bf313